# where'd the webcontrol's viewstate go?

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls, viewstate, web-controls

A `TextBox` is a `WebControl` which is a `Control` which has a `ViewState` property.

So why when I type '.' after `myTextBox` doesn't the ViewState property appear in the list of properties and methods?

Comment: Why would you want to do this ?

Comment: It's not that I wanted to do it, I was just surprised when I didn't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's for use with custom controls that need to keep a viewstate, not for external modification. It's `protected` (i.e. only accessible from derived objects) for a reason.

For example, if you created a slider control that kept a viewstate for which position it was at, you would need to use the `ViewState` property. But there's no reason for anything else to use your slider control's viewstate.

Answer (score 2):

You can't see it because it's protected.

Here's the property from metadata:

```
[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
protected virtual StateBag ViewState { get; }
```

Interaction with the ViewState StateBag is handled through the SaveViewState and LoadViewState methods, which are also protected and only accessible to the control.

You should not need to do anything with the control's ViewState. It will maintain itself. You do however have access to the ViewState on the page.

Comment: No, `BrowsableAttribute` only applies to the designer. It's invisible because it's `protected`.

Comment: @minitech: Thank you. Got confused with EditorBrowsable attribute. Fixed my answer.